# Web Scraping, load more data into a HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape data from the following web page https://www.racingpost.com/bloodstock/sales/catalogues/5/2023-12-04

I am using beatiful soup and have requested the html as seen below. The soup returned contains 50 rows of data, which correspond to the first 50 rows you see on the website when you first load the HTML. However I dont know how to access the next 950+ rows of data thats avaible when you click on the bar below the table of data. I would like to scrape the data for the hidden rows of data as well. The reqex returns the rows of data I want in a string, anyone who runs the below code should get 50 strings returned in the list of raw_data, I am looking to get 1065 rows of data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment
import requests
import numpy as np
import time
import re



url = 'https://www.racingpost.com/bloodstock/sales/catalogues/5/2023-12-04'

res = requests.get(url)

print(res.status_code)

soup = BS(res.content, "html.parser")

    
string = str(soup.find_all("script", type="text/javascript")[1])


raw_data = re.findall(r'\{"lot(.*?)\}', string)
```

Comment: Look into selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to parse HTML at all, just load all the pages:

```
import requests

page_metadata = requests.get('https://www.racingpost.com/bloodstock/sales/catalogues/5/2023-12-04/data.json').json()
totalPages = page_metadata['pagination']['totalPages']

for page in range(1, totalPages + 1):
    response = requests.get('https://www.racingpost.com/bloodstock/sales/catalogues/5/2023-12-04/data.json', params={
        'page': str(page),
    })
    data: list[dict] = response.json()['rows']
    print(data)
```

Comment: That works perfect

Comment: Quick follow up question, how did you know to put /data.json on the end of the HTML?

Comment: Open the page in the browser and check the networking tab. You will see what data is being loaded.

Comment: Thanks Simon, any tips on how to scrape the following html? In particular the last 6 rows. https://www.racingpost.com/profile/horse/3763274/kerkyra-island/form.  I pulled a request into beautiful soup like above but when I search through the string I cant find anything to do with the data loaded on the webpage, I flicked through the network tab but I cant find the html they use to populate the page with data, it seems harder to find then the above example